# How do I install eyed3 on Mac properly?

Tags: python, terminal, pip, eyed3

I got the following error when I was attempting to install eyed3 in Terminal. May I know how do I rectify this error and install it correctly?

```
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dir_util.py", line 76, in mkpath
        "could not create '%s': %s" % (head, exc.args[-1]))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/eyed3': Permission denied

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/_l/ybspdsy946n9_jj1l7vplt540000gn/T/pip-build-j4vod5/eyed3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/_l/ybspdsy946n9_jj1l7vplt540000gn/T/pip-SEUrpQ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_l/ybspdsy946n9_jj1l7vplt540000gn/T/pip-build-j4vod5/eyed3/
```

Comment: after you run your command (and fail) try running: `sudo !!`

Comment: `sudo pip install eyeD3`